# Is that a secure way? Redux React Authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, authentication, redux

I‘m developing an adminpage with login functionality using Node.js, react and Redux.

For the login I used jwt. My question is, is it safe to use this? Because, i set Provider with the store around my App. And Inside  i check if the `user.isauthenticated()` then `adminpage` Else `loginpage`.

What worries me is the store. It is the same store in the loginpage and in the adminpage. So I have access from the login page to the store which is connected to the adminpage.

Would not it be safer to have two separate stores?

Comment: I assume you verify user on server with all the calls?

Comment: static isUserAuthenticated() {
      return localStorage.getItem('token') !==null;
  }. My Function in the Client side To check is the User authenticated.  my Server send a toke if the login was success.

Comment: So they can get to the admin stuff on the client. They still need to make calls to the apis on the server.  Those endpoints should be verifying they can access that data. Check everything on the server..... basic rule of thumb with any application.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing on the front end is “safe”. The real question is how you handle authentication/authorization in your backend. JWT is definitely a secure method for authentication, but keep in mind that the payload can be decoded by anyone, so any information stored in a JWT is visible to anyone who can access the token.

The safety consideration is this: could a user authenticate using your front end service, then use that token to access information from your backend that does not in some way belong to them? If you’ve built your backend properly, then your front end stores won’t be able to leak any information, because they won’t be able to obtain any information the user wasn’t already authorized to view/edit.

One scenario to keep in mind with front end security:
A user logs in, and proprietary data is stored by your front end app (whether redux/localstorage/etc). When that user logs out, if that data remains in the store, could another user log in and then view it somehow? Hopefully not. Your logout methods should remove any sensitive data from that frontend app, so any future user won’t have access to it.

I hope that helps. I might not have addressed redux directly, but that is because security is primarily a backend concern. Redux shouldn’t be relied upon to keep data safe, unless it is deleting stuff permanently from areas that unauthorized users could access later.